# Android SQLite Formulas

Tags: android, database, sqlite, formulas

I'm creating a small and simple app to use with my poker league. I've created a small DB that I simply enter the player name, who took them out, and what place they went out in. All of that works just fine. What I need to do is implement the point system that I use so that the points column in the database is automatically populated with the players points based on when they went out of the tournament. I don't have my code with me on this computer, so I'll explain the process as best I can here.

Heres the Table columns:

```
[ID], [Player], [Hitman], [Rank], [Points]
```

As I said, the app is quite simple. I enter the player name that went out (player), the player that took them out (hitman), and what place they went out in (rank). Touching "Add" inserts this information into the DB (the ID column auto increments). This populates the DB to ...

```
1...player1...hitman...18...null

2...player2...hitman...17...null
```

-etc-

I need to add in my points formula so that the [Points] column gets populated. The formula is fairly simple...`(50-(r*3)+(2*h)+(t-r))`.

```
* r =rank
* h=hits
* t=total players
```

For example, there are 18 players and a player goes out in 15th place after taking out two other people. The formula would read the following way:

```
* (50-(15*3)+(2*2)+(18-15)

* or (50-45+4+3)
```

...for a total of 12 points (yes, some players do end up in negative points).

How do I write my code to populate the points columns after entering in the data as described above?

I'm using Eclipse v4.2.1 with a Target SDK of 19 and running the app on a galaxy s5.

Thank you for the help!

Here's what I have for the database code...
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "players.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "player_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "HITMAN";
public static final String COL_4 = "PLACE";
public static final String COL_5 = "POINTS";

//variables to test formula
int rk, hits, seats;                                    // integer for Rank and Points
String formulaa = "(50-(3*rk)";                             // "(50-(3*rk)+(2*hits)+(rk-seats)";
String sqlPoints = "select "+formulaa+" AS "+COL_5+" from "+ TABLE_NAME;            // sql query string
        // To show points --> Cursor pts = db.rawQuery(sqlPoints, null);


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);                 // super (context, name, factory, version)

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, HITMAN TEXT, PLACE TEXT, POINTS INTEGER)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate (db);

}

public boolean insertData(String name, String hitman, String place) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, hitman);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, place);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}

public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from  " + TABLE_NAME, null);

    return res;

}

public boolean updateData(String id, String name, String hitman, String place) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
    contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, hitman);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, place);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[]{id });
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteData(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[] {id});

}
```

}

Comment: Something like this `SELECT ... , (50 - (Rank * 3) + (2 * Hits) + (NumPlayers - Rank)) AS Points FROM ... WHERE Player = 1` (or `WHERE Player = 'Ringo'`) would do the trick.

Comment: Why not just calculate the points in Java code and insert the number?

Comment: @nasch I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Hrundi Yeah, that's pretty much the query, but I also have to write it so the named variables are accounted for, and that's part of my problem....I think.  Yes, it does suck to be a newbie coder, but I hope to get there some day.  :-)

Comment: No, no: the "named variables" are your field names. `AS Points` puts the result into a calculated field (which I named Points), which appears in your query result set and can be retrieved in your cursor. Obviously, this is just pseudo code, must be adapted to your table structure.

Comment: You don't know how to do math in Java, or you don't know how to insert a number in your database?